# Universal translation throughout an environment?

Tags: science-fiction, language, interspecies-relations

Related to another question I had—-if there was something in a sci-fi environment that allowed for everyone there to understand each other, by letting every language be understood by anyone under the effects of the environment’s “translation field”, how could it alter the brain to work? For example, is it possible for someone to inhale an alien gas of some sort and for it to impact and alter their brain so that they may comprehend any language? How might it do so?

Comment: You've already asked a similar question and chosen an answer. What is different in this question and why doesn't the other one suffice? I'm Voting To Close (VTC) as duplicate for now.

Comment: Your previous question asked for a drug, this one for "something which impacts and alter their brain", which is nothing more than a synonym for drug

Comment: I guess the difference here is rather than a pill that an individual takes, it’s some sort of field or condition that fills an entire environment and effects everyone who is in it, and thus must be done in a way different than swallowing a drug like that—an environmental condition that impacts many at a time rather than an administered drug used on an individual scale

Comment: A drug can be used at a larger scale, depending on the drug. If it can be an aerosol, like you suggested with gas, it's identical to your other question.

Comment: Also please consider registering your account. It makes easier for you to keep track and maintain your own questions